# Releasing FeatureLayer COM object

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, .net

I am going through some code and trying to implement correct COM object releasing because currently in an error situation we cannot remove some generated files as the databases are kept locked.

I have already done this successfully in most places but this IFeatureLayer is causing some issues. Below is a code snippet in which we are modifying the datasource for each layer in map document. If I try to remove the database after this code has run, it fails as the database is locked. If I comment out the line featureLayer.FeatureClass = newFeatureClass; it successfully removes the database in same situation.

```
            IMap map = mapDocument.get_Map(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < map.LayerCount; i++)
        {
            ILayer layer = map.get_Layer(i);
            IFeatureLayer featureLayer = (IFeatureLayer)layer;
            IFeatureClass newFeatureClass = Utils.getFeatureClass(newDataSource, layer.Name);
            if (newFeatureClass == null)
            {
                string errorMessage = String.Format(
                    "Invalid data source. Feature class {0} was not found in the new data source.");
                Logger.Error(errorMessage);
                throw new ArgumentException(errorMessage);
            }
            IFeatureClass oldFeatureClass = featureLayer.FeatureClass;
            featureLayer.FeatureClass = newFeatureClass; // Not released correctly
            IMapAdmin2 mapAdmin = (IMapAdmin2)map;
            mapAdmin.FireChangeFeatureClass(oldFeatureClass, newFeatureClass);
            Utils.ReleaseObject(featureLayer);
            Utils.ReleaseObject(layer);
            Utils.ReleaseObject(oldFeatureClass);
            Utils.ReleaseObject(newFeatureClass);
        }
        Utils.ReleaseObject(map);
```

I have tried to release the mapAdmin, in which case it throws an exception as the map will get released as well. Setting mapAdmin to null didn't help. Also tried to release the featureLayer.FeatureClass but it didn't help either.

Comment: Just to clarify when you say "remove the database after this code has run..." are you trying to DELETE the workspace that the _oldFeatureClass_ came from?

Comment: No, the database where newFeatureClass is coming from (newDataSource). I release the newDataSource and the map document before deletion.

Comment: Can't edit the previous comment anymore...

No, I am trying to delete the database where newFeatureClass is coming from (newDataSource). And I also release the newDataSource and the map document before deletion. I am just testing this if an exception happens, then we need to remove all generated files but it fails currently.

What we do is copy the map document somewhere and change its datasource to _newDataSource_. As I remember when I tried to run this code line by line, the _oldFeatureClass_ was null when I got it from the featureLayer.